Use XML path in SQL Server 2012 with a temp table?
I am on version 2012 and need to use  FOR XML PATH to get a comma separated string for like projects. I have a temp table that I have compiled and would like to combine people based on project numbers. The results combine all people into one list for all projects. I am looking to get specific to project.
select #Team.WBS1, 
    stuff((
        Select ',', #Team.Team as [text()]
        from #Team
        Where #team.WBS1 = #team.wbs1
        for xml path('')
    ), 1, 1, '') 
from #Team

I am getting the same results for every project number.



Project
People




1
john, jim, sean, billy


1
john, jim, sean, billy


1
john, jim, sean, billy


1
john, jim, sean, billy


2
john, jim, sean, billy


3
john, jim, sean, billy


3
john, jim, sean, billy


4
john, jim, sean, billy


4
john, jim, sean, billy



I need results like this



Project
People




1
john, jim, sean, billy


2
billy


3
jim, sean,


4
john, jim,  billy



Data looks like this



Project
People




1
john


1
jim


1
sean


1
billy


2
billy


3
jim


3
sean


4
john


4
jim,  billy




You need to use a different alias for your table in your sub-query.

its all coming from one table, not sure what you mean

Yes, but you are trying to correlate your sub-query with your outer query, and because it's the same table you need to differentiate it. This #team.WBS1 = #team.wbs1 is like saying 1=1 because it's not differentiating inner and outer

I assume the last row of your "data looks like this" should actually be 2 rows

Does this answer your question: String_agg for SQL Server before 2017 (Specifically I cover how you do this in my answer.)

that worked, i differentiated . PERFECT Thank you so much but i am still getting duplicate projects with same results, is there a "distinct" i should be using somewhere?

Probably the group by mentioned in one of the answers

You need to do some grouping first:
WITH data AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    (
    VALUES  (1, N'john')
    ,   (1, N'jim')
    ,   (1, N'sean')
    ,   (1, N'billy')
    ,   (2, N'billy')
    ,   (3, N'jim')
    ,   (3, N'sean')
    ,   (4, N'john')
    ,   (4, N'jim, billy')
) t (Project,People)
)
SELECT  Project
,   STUFF((
    SELECT  ',' + People
    FROM    data dInner
    WHERE   dInner.Project = d.Project
    FOR xml path(''), type
    ).value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS People
FROM    data d
GROUP BY project

And "join" the subquery table with the main one.
Actually, my advice would be to always use aliases for tables, this avoids a lot of errors with incorrect JOINs.
Output:



Project
People




1
john,jim,sean,billy


2
billy


3
jim,sean


4
john,jim, billy



A little side-note is that it's good to use an ORDER BY when doing the FOR XML thing, so the values are always sorted the same way

I gave a snapshot of the data, there are 312 projects (will get bigger as time goes on) with over 20+ (will grow as new projects get added). Grouping all of them doesnt seem feasable. I would love to use String_Agg but 2012 doesnt suport it.

I just mean you need to add GROUP BY to the outer part, so you don't get duplicates :)

Alias the tables with different aliases:
   select distinct t1.WBS1, 
        stuff((
            Select ',', t2.Team as [text()]
            from #Team t2
            Where t2.WBS1 = t1.wbs1
            for xml path('')
        ), 1, 1, '') 
    from #Team t1;

DBFiddle demo

There should be a way to force downvoters to make an explanation, especially if it is taking them for months to think about it.
